# The best way to combine two active record queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

What difference between two approaches shown below and what is better:

```
        user.photos & Photo.public
```

and

```
        user.photos.where('photos.id IN (?)', Photo.public.select(:id))
```

Is there better way to combine two active record queries ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first will be using an array join, the second is doing two queries, neither is as efficient as adding another scope to your Photo model:

```
 # Photo Model
  scope :public, where {:public => true }
  scope :user, lambda { |user| where("user_id = ?", user) }

  # Controller
  Photo.public.user(user)
```

Comment: For some reason I can't do this? I only can make two queries separately, not within one scope

Comment: Its not one scope, it's two scopes in a chain - which is quite a common usage, post your model and maybe we can find out why this isn't working for you.

Answer (score 1):

Given that Photo#public is a scope, ex.:

```
scope :public, -> { where(:public => true) }
```

You can simply write

```
user.photos.public
```

Comment: For some reason I can't do this? I only can make two queries separately, not within one scope

Comment: @AntonChumakov is photos an association?

Answer (score 0):

In the case you can't use a new scope, I would suggest you:

```
user.photos.merge(Photo.public)
```

Comment: The problem is that scopes user.photos and Photo.public can't be in single SQL query. They conflict with each other. Also in this example